# Woocommerce mini-cart.php doesnt override the template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to create my custom mini-cart widget and followed the tutorials. E.g. created child-theme (Hello Elementor 2.6.1) put it under hello-elementor-child/woocommerce/cart/mini-cart.php. Even the Woocommerce status tells me that my file overrides the template so i should be fine.

`Überschrieben      hello-elementor-child/woocommerce/cart/mini-cart.php`

But when i change anything in the mini-cart.php file nothing happens with the widget. Even when i change the code in the plugin nothing changes...

I already reset caches used private browser windows etc. nothing happens...

Anyone suggestions?
Wrong theme?
Wrong setup of child theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i found the solution:
The cart-widget i'm using is provided by Elementor Pro. Elementor itself has a  (weird) option to enable or disable this cart under Elementor > Settings > Integrations - here you have to disable the cart in order for your template override to work.